# Get the ID from "append(<tr><td="ID">..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, dynamic, firebase-realtime-database

I am filling a table with some data that I get from firebase database, and for that I am using append()

```
$("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + nome + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + marca + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + modelo + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + setor + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + responsavel + "</td>" +

                          "<td><div buttons>"+
                                  "<button>Delete</button>"+" "+
                                  "<button>Edit</button>"+
                                "</div></td></tr>");
```

But then, I don't know how to use the "Remove" and "Edit" buttons on each row of the table, shouldn't I have the ID of each row? But then, how do I get the ID of each row if the rows are added dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object ID from your data model ... add that as an attribute to the row.

Then use a traverse to [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) row to isolate instances

Following assumes a button with class added :

```
<tr data-id="idFromFirebaseObject">
    .... 
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
```

Then use **event delegation** to account for elements that don't yet exist at run time

```
$("#table_body").on('click','.delete-btn', function(e){
   // "this" is element event occurred on
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
       rowId = $row.data('id');
       // do your thing with FB then in success callback remove row
       ....
      $row.remove();
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i couldn't test it before... Well now that i actually tried testing this, i cant understand this... What do you mean by "idFromFirebaseObject"? "And the rowId = $row.data('id');" is the 'id' the same as the "idFromFirebaseObject"?

Comment: each object you add to firebase  gets  a unique identifier when you save it

Comment: i'm using push() to save the data, so it automatically generates an ID for the object, i can get the reference for this object with .key, but i add objects on firebase on another page, and list them on this page, so i'm having trouble on how to get this reference...

Comment: same way you get `modelo`, `nome` etc

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the right way to do it, but i'm having trouble getting the automatically generated ID from firebase, but that would be changing the subject of the topic, i'll create another topic for this, thanks so much for the help!